# Mega Downloads on Mac OSX

Tags: download, mac, osx, mega

It is known that in Windows mega uses the fileSystem API, which basically writes the file to a sandboxed section of your local file system:

```
AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System\
```

Where does mega storages the downloads on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software%3afseventer%3astart) I was able to find the location:

```
/Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/File System/
```

Replace {username} by the current user.